# Deleting all the matching items in single linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have the following code which I implemented to delete all the nodes for the **matching value**. My code handles all the 63 varieties of test case scenarios including scenarios like deleting 1 from linked list 1->1, leaving the linked list empty.

```
  public ListNode RemoveElements(ListNode head, int val) {
      if(head != null)
    {
        ListNode current = head;
        ListNode prevNode;
        while(current !=null && current.next != null)
        {
            prevNode = current;
            if(current.val == val)
            {
                current.val = current.next.val;
                current.next = current.next.next;
            }
            else
                current = current.next;
        }


        int count = 0;
        ListNode p = head;
        ListNode pBefore = null;
        while(p != null)
        {
            if(p.next != null)
                pBefore = p;
            p = p.next;
            count++;
                        }

        if(current.val == val)
        {
            if(count == 1)
             head = null;
             else if(count > 1)
                pBefore.next = null;
        }

    }
    return head;     

}
```

I'm sure this can be optimized and it would be great if someone can share the best way to delete all the matching items in single linked list.

I tried searching on Google, but everywhere it is handled as part of a `SingleLinked` list custom class having head and tail node access. In my case, I am handling in a method and I have access only to the head of the list through the input parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! One clarifying question. You said you want to optimise the script, did you mean with performance or optimised some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several issues jump in the eyes:

- very complicated logic
- very strange "removal" logic: copy value from next node + delete next node
- is recommended to use braces even on single statement if-else
- messy indentation

This can be done a lot simpler, by using a dummy node:

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode();
dummy.next = head;

ListNode runner = dummy;
while (runner.next != null)
{
    if (runner.next.val == val)
    {
        runner.next = runner.next.next;
    }
    else
    {
        runner = runner.next;
    }
}

return dummy.next;
```

Answer (score 2):

## ListNode

Though `ListNode` isn't a bad name - it could be better. Consider `SinglyLinkedListNode` (`LinkedListNode` already exists in the BCL)

Properties should be PascalCased and not use abbreviations, `next` should be `Next` and `val` should be `Value`.

```
public class SinglyLinkedListNode
{
     public SinglyLinkedListNode Next { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is a good candidate for a generic class too:

```
public class SinglyLinkedListNode<T>
{ 
    public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you aren't limited to just integers.

## RemoveElements

I'd say it's a good name

You should return early to save some indentation:

```
public ListNode RemoveElements(ListNode head, int val)
{
    if(head == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    // omitted
```

You aren't using `prevNode` you should remove it.

I was part way through writing a better solution but Janos beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

Your code mixes two approaches for deleting a node from a single-linked list:

1. remove the the node directly given a known predecessor
2. copy the value from the next node, then delete the next node (useful if the predecessor is unknown)

Because  you already know the predecessor, I would advise to choose the first approach. I also like having a seperate method for unlinking a node; it can used for various list operations.

```
public ListNode unlinkNode(ListNode prev, ListNode cur)
{
  if (prev == null) {
    head = cur.next;
  } else {
    prev.next = cur.next;
  }
  return cur.next;
}

public ListNode RemoveElements(ListNode head, int val) {
   ListNode prevNode = null;
   ListNode current = head;
   while(current != null)
   {
     if (current.val == val) {
       current = unlinkNode(prevNode, current);
     } else {
       prevNode = current;
       current = current.next;
     }
   }
   return head;
}
```